# Inserted a row in postgres and after sometime it is rollbacking

Tags: postgresql

I inserted a row in postgresql manually and after some time I can see it is rollbacking and also I see in database activity lot of  idle(Client: ClientRead) session are there.Please let me know how I can solve this

Comment: COMMIT the transaction. By the way, it's hard to believe that you really use PostgreSQL version 9.1, that one is EOL since October 2016.

Comment: Sorry, I am not using PostgreSQL version 9.1..BTW...I committed the transaction, but no luck...it is rolling back

Comment: @ravii no, it isn't. You either didn't commit the transaction and it rolled back when you disconnected or are misunderstanding something else.